Compare build artifacts from two different branches via github actions
How can I compare build artifacts from two different branches (head and PR branch) via github actions?
In my case I am trying to compare all files that was generated by the build against my main branch and check if user has build the code manually before pushing the changes or not. Even if build didn't generate more files, but the content of those artifacts has changed and user didn't build the code, how to catch the problem?
This is my fully CI workflow working:
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version:
          - '3.10'
          - '3.11'
          - '3.12'
          - '3.13'
    permissions:
      contents: write
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Setup Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-python@v5
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: |
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install -y powershell
          make $(VENV_DIRECTORY)

      - name: Lint
        run: make lint V=1

      - name: Test
        run: make test V=1

      - name: Build
        run: make build V=1

      - name: Upload Artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        if: matrix.python-version == '3.13'
        with:
          name: Artifacts
          path: | 
            Demo/src/ArtifactsFileTemplates
            !Demo/src/ArtifactsFileTemplates/Diagnostics/**
          retention-days: 15
          compression-level: 0

  lint-bicep:
    name: Lint Bicep Files
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Install Bicep CLI
        run: az bicep install

      - name: Download Artifacts
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: Artifacts
          path: ./Artifacts/

      - name: List Artifacts
        run: ls -R ./Artifacts

      - name: Lint Bicep Files
        run: |
          echo "Finding all Bicep files in ./Artifacts/Bicep/Templates"
          for bicepTemplateFile in $(find ./Artifacts/Bicep/Templates -type f -name "*.bicep"); do
            echo "Linting $bicepTemplateFile"
            az bicep lint --file "$bicepTemplateFile" || exit 1
          done
          echo "Finding all Bicep parameter files in specific folders"
          for folder in DEV01 INT01 TEST01; do
            echo "Searching in ./Artifacts/Bicep/Parameters/$folder"
            if [ -d "./Artifacts/Bicep/Parameters/$folder" ]; then
              for bicepParamFile in $(find ./Artifacts/Bicep/Parameters/$folder -type f -name "*.bicepparam"); do
                echo "Linting $bicepParamFile"
                az bicep lint --file "$bicepParamFile" || exit 1
              done
            else
              echo "Folder ./Artifacts/Bicep/Parameters/$folder does not exist."
            fi
          done

This is what I have tried:
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version:
          - '3.10'
          - '3.11'
          - '3.12'
          - '3.13'
    permissions:
      contents: write
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Setup Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-python@v5
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}

      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: |
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get install -y powershell
          make $(VENV_DIRECTORY)

      - name: Lint
        run: make lint V=1

      - name: Test
        run: make test V=1

      - name: Build Artifacts
        run: make build V=1

      - name: Backup Repository Artifacts
        run: |
          echo "Backing up repository artifacts..."
          cp -r Demo/src/ArtifactsFileTemplates Demo/src/ArtifactsFileTemplates_repo

      - name: Check for Artifact Mismatches
        run: |
          echo "Comparing repository and generated artifacts..."
          diff -r Demo/src/ArtifactsFileTemplates Demo/src/ArtifactsFileTemplates_repo || { echo "Artifact mismatch detected! Ensure all changes are built and committed before pushing."; exit 1; }

      - name: Upload Artifacts
        if: matrix.python-version == '3.13'
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: Artifacts
          path: |
            Demo/src/ArtifactsFileTemplates
            !Demo/src/ArtifactsFileTemplates/Diagnostics/**
          retention-days: 15
          compression-level: 0

  lint-bicep:
    name: Lint Bicep Files
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Install Bicep CLI
        run: az bicep install

      - name: Download Artifacts
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: Artifacts
          path: ./Artifacts/

      - name: List Artifacts
        run: ls -R ./Artifacts

      - name: Lint Bicep Files
        run: |
          echo "Finding all Bicep files in ./Artifacts/Bicep/Templates"
          for bicepTemplateFile in $(find ./Artifacts/Bicep/Templates -type f -name "*.bicep"); do
            echo "Linting $bicepTemplateFile"
            az bicep lint --file "$bicepTemplateFile" || exit 1
          done
          echo "Finding all Bicep parameter files in specific folders"
          for folder in DEV01 INT01 TEST01; do
            echo "Searching in ./Artifacts/Bicep/Parameters/$folder"
            if [ -d "./Artifacts/Bicep/Parameters/$folder" ]; then
              for bicepParamFile in $(find ./Artifacts/Bicep/Parameters/$folder -type f -name "*.bicepparam"); do
                echo "Linting $bicepParamFile"
                az bicep lint --file "$bicepParamFile" || exit 1
              done
            else
              echo "Folder ./Artifacts/Bicep/Parameters/$folder does not exist."
            fi
          done

